# Error make: *** [obj/QTLtoosl.o] Error 1

Tags: software-installation

Can anybody help me? when I use the make command on step 8 on https://qtltools.github.io/qtltools/. This is the output on installing QTLtool from their documentation. I am using ubuntu version 18.04.4 and downloaded the 1.3.1 of the QTL. Please someone guide me on this?

[Error on the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJiFv.png)

Comment: According to the [Compilation examples](https://qtltools.github.io/qtltools/pages/basic_compilation.html), `make` should come in Step 8, **after** modifying the Makefile to *"set the necessary variables"*

Comment: Yeah its a typo. Its on step 8 sir

Comment: So... did you set the variables? What did you set them to? The error you're getting mentions "missing paths after `-I`"

Comment: this is what I set sir @steeldriver

Comment: `BOOST_INC=/usr/include
BOOST_LIB=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
RMATH_INC=$(HOME)/Tools/R-4.0.2/src/include
RMATH_LIB=$(HOME)/Tools/R-4.0.2/src/nmath/standalone
HTSLD_INC=$(HOME)/Tools/htslib-1.10.2
HTSLD_LIB=$(HOME)/Tools/htslib-1.10.2`

Comment: I remove the parenthesis because I'm getting an error 'command not found'

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the first 20 lines or so of the Makefile (ex. `head -n 20 Makefile`)

Comment: And in any case nake sure the system id fully updated *before* installing software. Ubuntu 18.04 should report as 18.04.6, not .4. This means you're missing LOTS of updates. And consider installing a newer release in order to not have this work in vain, Ubuntu 18.04 has only 5 months of support left.